# Issue with JS Wide Showcase not stretching full width on mobile

Tags: wordpress, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building this site http://www.saraswati.co.uk

If you view here:

http://www.saraswati.co.uk/?page_id=12

You will see I am using a Wide Showcase Wordpress Plugin, the site is built in Wordpress using Bootstrap and is Responsive.

Once you get beneath the Bootstrap 767px breakpoint there is some CSS code somewhere causing the page to stretch beyond the width of the Wide Showcase, I want to stop this.

So if you view on Mobile, it is fine everywhere else you will see on the right hand side there is about 60px of the homepage background caused by some CSS.

I've tested out switching on and off various CSS settings in Web Inspector, but haven't rooted out what is causing the problem.

Help would be great.

Ant

Comment: The problem is coming from the Wide Showcase Wordpress plugin's CSS.

Comment: Thanks Henry, anything more detailed on that, thanks.

Comment: I just took a look at the code. Please see my answer below which may help. Just to note, the slider image doesn't behave very well at all at mobile screen size. It might be worth you raising a support ticket with the plugin developer to alert them to the issue. They'd probably appreciate it

Comment: It's a bit broken it's a nice effect, but I don't think the developer has put any work into the responsive side of things. I've had to do a lot of CSS hacking to make it presentable across different devices, not finished yet though. Thanks for your help:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding some of the Wide Showcase Wordpress plugin's styles.

```
@media ( max-width: 767px ) and ( min-width: 0px ) {
    .wdRegularSliderMin {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}

body {
    width: auto;
}
```

Adding that to your WordPress theme's `style.css` will get rid of the horizontal scroll bar you're seeing on mobile and tablet screen sizes.

Comment: That hasn't fixed it, I now have space flanking either side as opposed to just the right hand side, I think there is a parent container setting that amount of space and it is being inherited by the plugin css below 767px breakpoint, just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Ok solved, Bootstrap has a lot of code which is a blessing and a curse, below 767px breakpoint the padding-left and right on the body was set to 20px, I tried to hack over the problem with negative margin left, once set to 0px, I then found the bootstrap coded padding below 767px on the body.

Comment: My code just fixes the horizontal scroll problem. It wasn't intended to fix the flanking space either side of the image. Glad you were able to find a solution for that too.

Comment: Cool thanks yeah that was the issue I was fixing, thanks for your help.